# Is a permanent exoskeleton made of a stereom-like material plausible?

Tags: creature-design, insectoid, skeletons, natural-growth

Could an animal have an exposed exoskeleton with no tissue covering that is never cast off and is not secreted by a mantle, if the exoskeleton was made of a living tissue like stereom? The living components could secrete new material on the outside and remove material on the inside, allowing the exoskeleton to grow and be kept throughout the animal's life, similar to an endoskeleton?

Comment: The skeleton of echinoderms (because you said stereom) is barely an *endo*skeleton -- it is very close to the outside of the body, being covered by the skin. There are no muscles etc. between the skeleton and the skin. (And I don't get how "living components" would be able to operate both on the inside and the outside of an exoskeleton.)

Comment: Turtles? ......

Comment: @jamesqf Turtles have a layer of tissue over the bony shell

Comment: @Ichthys King: Sure, that outer layer of tissue is how new layers of exoskeleton are secreted.  Much like the inner bark of trees...

Comment: @jamesqf This question askes if a living stereom-type substance could grow without that outer tissue

Comment: @Ichthys King: Then you need to re-word the question, because it certainly isn't clear that that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to do with it.

If you need it to function like the exoskeleton of an insect or crustacean the answer is no. If it just needs to act as armor and weak structural support, then sort of.

First to excrete tissue on the outside of the exoskeleton there has to be tissue on the outside of the exoskeleton to excrete it, so your second idea is impossible.

As for stereom, first enchinoderms have multiple tissue layers between the ossicles and the outside of the body, but in theory it could be the outermost layer but there would still have ot be soft tissue on the outside it is just the same tissue that lies between the ossicles. Stereom ossicles are excreted by the tissue they lie in, but this also means it cannot be contiguous, which makes it a pretty weak exoskeleton, fine for slow moving echinoderms useless in something that needs to move quickly or function in air.

The closest you can get is what our ancestors had, bone only a single tissue layer from the outside, and protruding through in many places. but this puts severe limits on the shapes you can achieve, and again it cannot be contiguous.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't living cells in the stereom secrete the outer layers instead of an extra tissue layer?

Comment: They could but they still need the same number of cells so the difference would be semantic. They surround the ossicles, so you have tissue on the outside no matter what.